# Does Metal support anything like glDepthRange()?

Tags: metal, vertex-shader, depth-buffer

I'm writing some metal code that draws a skybox. I'd like for the depth output by the vertex shader to always be 1, but of course, I'd also like the vertices to be drawn in their correct positions.

In OpenGL, you could use `glDepthRange(1,1)` to have the depth always be written out as 1.0 in this scenario. I don't see anything similar in Metal. Does such a thing exist? If not, is there another way to always output 1.0 as the depth from the vertex shader?

What I'm trying to accomplish is drawing the scenery first and then drawing the skybox to avoid overdraw. If I just set the z component of the outgoing vertex to 1.0, then the geometry doesn't draw correctly, obviously. What are my options here?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can specify the fragment shader output (return value) format roughly so:

```
struct MyFragmentOutput {
    // color attachment 0
    float4 color_att [[color(0)]];
    // depth attachment
    float depth_att [[depth(depth_argument)]]
}
```

as seen in the section "Fragment Function Output Attributes" on page 88 of the Metal Shading Language Specification (https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf). Looks like `any` is a working value for `depth_argument` (see here for more: [In metal how to clear the depth buffer or the stencil buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964035/in-metal-how-to-clear-the-depth-buffer-or-the-stencil-buffer))

Then you would set you fragment shader to use that format

```
fragment MyFragmentOutput interestingShaderFragment
// instead of: fragment float4 interestingShaderFragment
```

and finally just write to the depth buffer in your fragment shader:

```
MyFragmentOutput out;
out.color_att = float(rgb_color_here, 1.0);
out.depth_att = 1.0;
return out;
```

Tested and it worked.

Comment: Writing it out in the fragment shader is too late. I need to not call the fragment shader if the depth is calculated to be behind already-drawn objects.

Comment: Then I would look into `early_fragment_tests` (a bit earlier in the same doc, ~previous page), not well versed in it but sounds like possibly what you need. Alternatively calling `discard_fragment();` as the first thing in the fragment shader (if `in.position.z > depth_treshhold`) could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! That does sound like what I need. However, I can't find any information on how it works beyond a few sentences saying it exists in the Metal Shading Language Spec. I'll keep digging, but if you know of any examples, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, don't know much more than that and don't think I will have time to dig.